# Debugging with when implementing abstract data type

Tags: debugging, abstract-data-type

I'm pretty new to programming and I am losing a lot of time with debugging. I am currently implementing Fibonacci heap. But when programming, since I don't have the visual form of the heap like we have in theory, it's a a little bit hard to keep track of the data structure and see if the methods are working correctly. The only way I know to check if the code works, is using the debugging in InteliJ and look at the attributes of each node and check that it's correct but it's taking a lot of time. So I wanted to ask, is there a more efficient way to debug when implementing abstract data types or abstract stuff in general?

Comment: Debugging is sometimes a slow and painful process, especially for any kind of recursive structure or code. But it's also sometimes very needed, and you simply have to let it take the time it takes.

Comment: Well, I'm glad to hear that then because I felt like I'm not being efficient